# How do I get the year from this column? (oracle apex)

Tags: sql, oracle-apex

I am trying to get the year from this one column in my physician table. I am trying to get just the year from all the physicians that were hired in the 'DATEHIRED' column but it is not working

```
select year(datehired)
from physician
```

the error message I'm getting is ORA-00904: "YEAR": invalid identifier

Data structure

[image]
This is what the table looks like

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The correct function in Oracle is `extract()`:

```
select extract(year from datehired)
from physician;
```

You can also extract it as a character:

```
select to_char(datehired, 'YYYY')
from physician;
```